Equation over integer numbers
Find all positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $z\ge 2$ and
$$3^x+5^x=y^z$$
By taking modulo 8, I proved $x$ odd and $z=3$ ($y$ is even and LHS is number that divisible by $8$ but $16$). How can I get further?

Sorry. It is my mistake. $z\ge 2$

Discussion on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820h2175409p16227555

There is no $y$ in your equation. Is there a typo?

For $x\geq2 $ and even, the $LHS \equiv2 (\mod4)$. So it is divisible by $2$ but not $4$, which is false since the RHS in this case is divisible by $4$.
For odd $x\geq2$ then the $LHS\equiv3+5(\mod8)$ so $LHS\equiv0(\mod8)$ So we must have $z=3$. Looking $(\mod9)$ we have that $x=3s$ because $n^3\equiv-1,0,1(\mod9)$. So the equation becomes $3^{3s}+5^{3s}=y^3 \iff 27^s+125^s=y^3$ and by Fermat's last theorem, there exist no integers satisfying this equation.

Why $z$ must be $3$?
